# applescript code for showing image property

Tags: image, properties, applescript

I am new to *applescript*. I want to develop an application in *applescript*.

Below is my code. And while running it, it's showing finder that can't make alias. Kindly help me.

```
property script_name : "image Tracker"
property script_description : "image property data finder"

--set the_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder for get the image property:") as Unicode text

--set the_folder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder for get the image property:")

set the_folder to (choose folder)

copy {"jpg", "png", "eps", "ai", "tif", "psd", "gif"} to validExtentions

tell application "Finder" to set fPaths to file the_folder
repeat with thisFilePath in fPaths
    if name extension of thisFilePath is in validExtensions then
        try
            tell application "Image Events"
                -- start the Image Events application
                launch
                -- open the image file
                set this_image to open this_file
                -- extract the properties record
                set the props_rec to the properties of this_image
                -- purge the open image data
                close this_image
                -- extract the property values from the record
                set the image_info to ""
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Name: " & (name of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "*********************************************" & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "File: " & (path of image file of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "File Type: " & (file type of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Res: " & item 1 of (resolution of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Color Space: " & (color space of props_rec) & return
                copy (dimensions of props_rec) to {x, y}
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Dimemsions: " & x & ", " & y
            end tell
        on error error_message
            display dialog error_message
        end try
    end if
end repeat

set myfile to open for access ("Macintosh HD:Users:varghese.pt:Desktop:") & "image_data.txt" with write permission
write image_info to myfile
close access myfile
```

---

If anyone found the answer, please send me the details.
Thanks in advance.

Nidhin Joseph

Comment: I suggest you remove your email address from the question; answers, if any, will be posted here, and you will be notified by the site itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me say up front: Unfortunately, in general, AppleScript is a finicky beast, and sometimes trial and error are your only friends.

There are several problems with your code - some obvious, one not:

- `validExtentions` is misspelled in the `copy {"jpg ...` statement - you later refer to with the (correctly spelled) name `validExtensions`
- In the `tell application "Finder"` command, you must replace `file` with `folder`.
- In command `set this_image to open this_file`, you must replace `this_file` with `(thisFilePath as text)`. NOTE: Parenthesizing and `as text` is crucial, as the file will otherwise be opened by *Finder* (and therefore open in Preview.app) - don't ask me WHY this is so.
- I also suggest replacing the hard-coded path in the write-to-file command with `(path to desktop as text) & "image_data.txt"`

If we put it all together, we get:

```applescript
copy {"jpg", "png", "eps", "ai", "tif", "psd", "gif"} to validExtensions

set the_folder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder" to repeat with thisFilePath in folder the_folder
    if name extension of thisFilePath is in validExtensions then
        try
            tell application "Image Events"
                # start the Image Events application
                launch
                # open the image file
                # set this_image to open thisFilePath
                set this_image to open (thisFilePath as text)
                # extract the properties record
                set the props_rec to the properties of this_image
                # purge the open image data
                close this_image
                # extract the property values from the record
                set the image_info to ""
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Name: " & (name of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "*********************************************" & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "File: " & (path of image file of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "File Type: " & (file type of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Res: " & item 1 of (resolution of props_rec) & return
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Color Space: " & (color space of props_rec) & return
                copy (dimensions of props_rec) to {x, y}
                set the image_info to the image_info & ¬
                    "Dimensions: " & x & ", " & y
                # my dlog(image_info)
            end tell
        on error error_message
            display dialog error_message
        end try
    end if
end repeat

set myfile to open for access (path to desktop as text) & "image_data.txt" with write permission
write image_info to myfile
close access myfile
```

Finally, you can improve the *performance* of your code by switching from enumerating files in the `Finder` context to enumerating in the `System Events` context:

If you substitute the following two lines for their current counterparts in the code above, your script will run much more quickly. Why, you ask? Again, I do not know.

- `tell application "System Events" to repeat with thisFilePath in alias (the_folder as text)`
- `set this_image to open (get path of thisFilePath)`

Comment: i used this code but this error again like file i all ready open and no data in image info variable while writing to file. pls help me. my usage of this application: i need to take some properties of images in a folder; image name wise. write all content into one file. thats it.

Comment: @aadhi: What, specifically, generates an error, and what is the error message>